# Windows 7 Install command prompt can't access the C drive

Tags: windows-7, command-line, installation, boot-to-vhd

I'm trying to create a new Windows 7 Professional VHD which I can dual boot to, following Scott Hanselman's [guide to creating a bootable VHD](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx).

When I get to the command prompt in the Windows 7 installation and try to create a VHD or select/attach a pre-created VHD file I get an error saying that `diskpart` can't find the path specified.

If I try and switch to the c drive using `cd c:` I see

```
c:\
x:\something\>
```

I already have a Windows 7 Ultimate install and my C drive is an SSD – if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, figured this out. After going to back into the windows installer and trying to load the drivers for my ssd I noticed that my c drive is actually showing up as the d drive in the windows install and the c drive was showing as a system reserved/recovery drive. A little random...

Also worth noting that you can't actually boot win7 pro from a vhd, what IT pro would want to do that? Its only available for ultimate and enterprise versions.

Comment: My drive letter was identified at the top of the "options" list that included Command Prompt.

Answer (score 9):

The command `cd c:` just shows the current directory in the C drive.

To change to the C drive, use either of the following commands:

```
cd /d c:

c:
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't change drives with `CD`, that's for Changing Directories.

To switch to another drive you just type `C:` (for example) and hit enter.  Or if you *really* want to use CD to switch directories AND drive you can use `CD /D C:\`.

Also, if doing it one of these ways still doesn't work, ensure you have the driver loaded for you controller (AHCI, RAID or whatnot) so that setup can see the drive.

Comment: Got to the c drive but I can't see any files or folders, how do I load the drivers for the drive?